# Can I get this angle ??

Tags: geometry

Step number (1) is correct or not?

and if correct can I get angle AEB?

[image]

Comment: What are you even asking? Please include more details about the question

Comment: It seems that data are not sufficient, I don't understand your work for step 1 and what is step one?

Comment: Step 1 is certainly NOT correct.  Triangle EFA is a right triangle while triangle AEC is not so they are NOT similar.

Comment: That's not how similarity works. You need to conserve dimensions ratio, shape...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that line $EF$ can be moved left and right without altering any of the given conditions. And doing this clearly changes $\angle AEB$. Thus the information provided is insufficient.

On your approach, it is  not correct because on adding that area, one triangle is right angled whereas other is obtuse.